# Why I am getting the "'Pool' object is not callable" Error from EEMD function in PyEMD when using its parallel argument?

Tags: python, multithreading, jupyter-notebook, parallel-processing

I have written the below code to perform parallel processing when computing IMFs through EEMD function in PyEMD library:

```
eemd = EEMD(parallel = True, processes = 8)
eemd.noise_seed(12345)
imfs = eemd.eemd(time_series.reshape(-1),None,8)
```

Running the above code, threw an error, as:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 4
      2 eemd = EEMD(parallel = True, processes = 8)
      3 eemd.noise_seed(12345)
----> 4 imfs = eemd.eemd(time_series.reshape(-1),None,8)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyEMD\EEMD.py:189, in EEMD.eemd(self, S, T, max_imf, progress)
    187 else:
    188     map_pool = map
--> 189 all_IMFs = map_pool(self._trial_update, range(self.trials))
    191 if self.parallel:
    192     map_pool.close()

TypeError: 'Pool' object is not callable
```

I am not sure what causes this problem. *A note that when I tried the same code without passing parallel and processes arguments, the code works perfectly fine.